# What will happen if I throw chocolate figure on hot red fan?

Tags: metals

What will happen if i throw chocolate figure on hot red fan.
Fan, of course, is sucking in my figure, but will it evaporate, or  it will be thrown away in liquid form?
Lets take fan with steel blades, and heat its blades to 1000°C.

Comment: I doubt chocolate has a boiling point - it would probably decompose before it can boil.

Comment: I think "Confectionery and Chocolate Engineering: Principles and Applications" can help at this question, but preview version did not gave me possibility to find an answer. Answers.com says that boiling point of chocolate is on 85 deg, so i think vaporization point is much lower 1000 deg, and part of chocolate will vaporize if it will touch fan blade.

Comment: @t.c: I guess you have never baked before? Or eaten freshly baked chocolate chip cookies? Or used a search engine to find the [melting point of chocolate](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=melting+point+chocolate&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest&gws_rd=ssl)?

Comment: @KyleKanos boiling point..not melting point.

Comment: I would be terrified at the thought of gaseous chocolate flowing into my nostrils and depositing somewhere within my lungs, if I were you.@KyleKanos

Comment: @t.c: Again, you have shown your lack of culinary experience. [Boiling chocolate](http://www.finecooking.com/articles/how-to-make-chocolate-fudge.aspx) is one way to make fudge. From what I can tell the melting point & boiling points are within a few degrees of each other, so the two are virtually identical.

Comment: @KyleKanos Chocolate is a mixture - not a compound, you'll never know what actually evaporates when chocolate 'boils', unless you collect the condensate (distil it).

Comment: @t.c: Irrelevant to the fact that the mixture *does in fact **boil***, contrary to your assertion!

Comment: @KyleKanos when you make fudge you are boiling the water out of the water-sugar-fat (both milkfat and chocolate fat) mixture.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the blades are inside a cage (typical of fans that I've seen, but given these fan blades are to be kept at 1000 C, this fan is not typical!), then the chocolate will be chopped pieces. These pieces will bounce around a bit until they are small enough to stay at the bottom of the cage where they will subsequently melt due to the radiant heat from the fan blades.